# Unable to use MSDeploy from Local to Remote Server

Tags: iis-7

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKhPs.png) Unable to Remote Deploy my Webservice on to the remote machine from local machine. I have two servers that i would be needing to enable web deployment from local system to remote server Windows 2012 system. Upon searching multiple resources i found below steps that need to be ensured before performing the remote deploy using MsDeploy from Local to Remote .

- Also Package works fine which is built from Visual Studio if i copy the files on to the remote server  and run the command file it is able to deply the windows service on to IIS locally . But i would need this to be deployed from my local machine to remote server* 
  Steps I tried :

  1. Ensure Web Deploy is installed.
  2. Remote Services are running.
  3. Under Management Service in IIS ensure Enable Remote connections
     is enabled.
  4. Ensure 80 and 8172 Ports are enabled and running ( ran the below steps )
  5. Web Deploy is installed on the server that i'm trying to deploy the 
     package.
  6. I try running the below code and it returns below error :
     Command I provide :

C:\Users\xxxxx>net start wmsvc 
The requested service has already been started.

C:\Users\xxxxxx>net start msdepsvc 
The requested service has already been started.

Command I provide :

C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3>msdeploy.exe -verb:sync -source:package="C:\Users\xxxxxx\Desktop\" -dest:auto="",ComputerName="https://serveripaddress:8172/MsDeploy.axd",UserName='domain/user',Password='password',AuthType='Basic' -allowUntrusted 
Info: Using ID 'someinfoid like :  92c-da-sd-2398as823...... is generated' for connections to the remote server.

Error Code: ERROR_DESTINATION_NOT_REACHABLE
More Information: Could not connect to the remote computer (""). On the remote computer, make sure that Web Deploy is installed and that `the required process ("Web Management Service") is started.
Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_DESTINATION_NOT_REACHABLE.
Error: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
Error count: 1.
Installed Web Deploy Components 
Ensured the Services are enabled ( Web Deploy / Remote Services ) 
Remote Server : Windows 2012 
Local System : Windows 10

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/publish/troubleshooting-web-deploy/web-deploy-error-codes#ERROR_DESTINATION_NOT_REACHABLE Did you check the firewall settings?

Comment: Hi yes i did also when i try running the same command on one of the servers it works . There are 2 Servers on One of the server Msdeploy works fine , same command when i try for other server it doesnt work .